# Pandas: Does pd.read_excel() need Excel to be installed for it to work?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if pd.read_excel() needs Microsoft Excel to be installed on the computer for it to work? I'm not sure if my customer will have Excel installed or not so I don't want the program to break down if it is not available.

Thanks!

Comment: No, It doesn't need.

Comment: No, it does't need that. It just reads the file format in with it's own algorithm independent of microsoft excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas's `pd.read_excel` uses [`xlrd`](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) package to read excel file.
So it wont need Microsoft Excel.